# Compressed file size after deflate

Tags: zip, zlib

I am using **deflate** function in **zlib** library to compress the file. How can I determine the size of the compressed file? Is it the element **total_out** that indicates the size of compressed file?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `deflate()` correctly, then you are accumulating or writing the compressed output, and can add up the number of output bytes yourself.  At each call, the amount of output is `strm.avail_out` before the `deflate()` call minus `strm.avail_out` after the call.  See [`zpipe.c`](http://zlib.net/zlib_how.html) for an example of the usage of `deflate()` and `inflate()`.

You can use `strm.total_out` for the total size of the compressed output *if* you know that that size will fit in an `unsigned long`.